# How to set a boost::optional back to an uninitialized state?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-optional

How can I "reset"/"unset" a `boost::optional`?

```cpp
optional<int> x;

if( x )
{
  // We won't hit this since x is uninitialized
}
x = 3;
if( x )
{
  // Now we will hit this since x has been initialized
}
// What should I do here to bring x back to uninitialized state?
if( x )
{
  // I don't want to hit this
}
```

Comment: It is a little bit of a mystery to me why there is no `optional::clear` or `optional::empty`.

Comment: Probably because there completely does not need to be one.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Can you elaborate?  I'm looking at this in the context of optional member variables where you want to essentially reset some of the state of an object.  Perhaps there's a better way of doing that.

Comment: @Guy: Instead, please explain (for pmr) why there needs to be an `optional::clear` or `optional::empty`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I didn't say there needs to be one :-) but I'll have a go, we have vector::clear and shared_ptr::reset so why is optional::clear or optional::reset different?  Are you saying that optional shouldn't be reset or are you asying that the assignment idiom is all one needs or are you saying there should only be one way of doing something?  I'm not arguing - just interested in your thoughts...

Comment: @GuySirton: pmr asked, and I answered! There is no need for the solutions pmr asked for, because the other solutions in this answer exist.

Comment: See also [How to disengage std::experimental::optional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897066/how-to-disengage-stdexperimentaloptional)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

```
x = boost::none;
```

Comment: [citation needed] _(That's why you "had" to evade the minimum limit on characters in answers.)_

Comment: Some more details: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/optional/doc/html/optional/reference.html#boost_optional.reference.header__boost_none_hpp_

Answer (score 15):

One simple way is this:

```
x = optional<int>(); //reset to default
```

Or simply:

```
x.reset();
```

It destroys the current value, leaving this uninitialized (default).

Comment: [`reset()` is deprecated](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/synopsis.html)

Comment: Here's [a more specific link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/detailed_semantics.html#reference_optional_reset). Basically, Benjamin's answer is the new `.reset();`.

Comment: `optional<T>::reset();` is simple to use right and difficult to use wrong, so why deprecate it? (citation to a famous guideline by Scott Meyers)