# How to disengage std::experimental::optional?

Tags: c++, c++14, option-type, boost-optional

With Boost I can create an optional in-place with:

```c++11
boost::optional<boost::asio::io_service::work> work = boost::in_place(boost::ref(io_service));
```

And disengage it with:

```c++11
work = boost::none;
```

With C++14 / experimental support, I can instead construct an optional in-place with:

```c++11
std::experimental::optional<boost::asio::io_service::work> work;
work.emplace(boost::asio::io_service::work(io_service));
```

But I'm at a loss for how to disengage it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
work = std::experimental::nullopt;
```

should disengage `work`.
The [library fundamental TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3908.html#optional) specifies in [optional.nullopt]:

> The struct `nullopt_t` is an empty structure type used as a unique
>   type to indicate a disengaged state for optional objects.

There is an appropriate assignment operator, [optional.object.assign]:

> ```
> optional<T>& operator=(nullopt_t) noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Effects:* If `*this` is engaged calls `val->T::~T()` to destroy the contained value; otherwise no effect.

To avoid constructing a `nullopt_t` object every time, a constant of this type is already declared:

> `struct nullopt_t{`*see below*`};`
>  
>   `constexpr nullopt_t nullopt(`*unspecified*`);`

Comment: In any case the only(ish) way you can construct an object of type `nullopt_t` is by copying `nullopt`.

Comment: @LucDanton ... or copying an object of type `nullopt_t` that was initialized by copying `nullopt`.

Comment: And so, ultimately, it all comes down to `nullopt`.

Answer (score 3):

This simplest way to disengage an optional is with `foo = {};`, which is resolved as move assignment from a disengaged prvalue `optional`. The specification actually goes out of its way to enable this syntax which would otherwise be ambiguous with assignment from the contained type. (See [[optional.object.assign] para 18-23 in N4023 for details](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4023.html#optional.object.assign))

Comment: Hmm, with my example that throws a compiler error:
error: use of deleted function 'std::experimental::optional<boost::asio::io_service::work>& std::experimental::optional<boost::asio::io_service::work>::operator=(std::experimental::optional<boost::asio::io_service::work>&&)'

Answer (score 1):

Having read through the headers, the correct way to disengage the std::experimental::optional appears to be:

```c++11
work = std::experimental::nullopt;
```